# How to debug "Mouse button stopped working"? Win10

Tags: windows-10, mouse-click

Third mouse button stopped working. I am a power user but I have no idea why it stopped.

It doesn't work from touchpad nor from external mouse. Other custom buttons work well.

**How to check what is blocking it?**

Settings of mouse/touchpad look all right.

I used this button a lot. It is very frustrating not to use it and not understanding what happened.

FYI: On my touchpad triple finger touch generats Third button clicked event. Windows 10.

Comment: Which one is the third-mouse button? What does it have to do with the touchpad?

Comment: Usually wheel can be clicked. This counts as third mouse button.